# Changing boolean value with React Bootstrap checkbox and hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap

Trying to change the isVegan object (nested boolean) with React Bootstrap checkbox and hooks. I can access the object without any issues (e.g. checkbox is checked if isVegan is true), but have been unable to modify the state. As you can see in the Redux dev tools (image link included), the isVegan object is passed through my state and is accessible. I have also used similar code for the other objects in the chef collection without any issues so believe the issue is either related to the checkbox or how the isVegan object is nested in the chef collection. (Lastly, I know some of the code below may be extra, I slimmed down my original file to simplify this example)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, setState } from 'react';
import { Form, Button, Row, Col, Tabs, Tab } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getChefDetails, updateChefProfile } from '../../actions/chefActions';
import { CHEF_UPDATE_PROFILE_RESET } from '../../constants/chefConstants';
import FormContainer from '../../components/FormContainer/FormContainer.component';

import './ProfileEditPage.styles.scss';

const ProfileEditPage = ({ location, history }) => {
  const [first_name, setFirstName] = useState('')
  const [last_name, setLastName] = useState('')
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('')
  const [isVegan, setIsVegan] = useState('')
  const [bio, setBio] = useState('')
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null)

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const chefDetails = useSelector(state => state.chefDetails)
  const { loading, error, chef } = chefDetails

  const chefLogin = useSelector(state => state.chefLogin)
  const { chefInfo } = chefLogin

  const chefUpdateProfile = useSelector(state => state.chefUpdateProfile)
  const { success } = chefUpdateProfile

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!chefInfo) {
      history.push('/login')
    } else {
      if(!chef || !chef.username || success) {
        dispatch({ type: CHEF_UPDATE_PROFILE_RESET })
        dispatch(getChefDetails('profile'))
      } else {
        setFirstName(chef.first_name)
        setLastName(chef.last_name)
        setUsername(chef.username)
        setEmail(chef.email)
        setBio(chef.bio)
        setIsVegan(chef.isVegan)
      }
    }
  }, [dispatch, history, chefInfo, chef, success])

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      setMessage('Passwords do not match')
    } else {
      dispatch(updateChefProfile({
        id: chef._id,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        username,
        email,
        password,
        bio,
        isVegan
      }))
    }
  }

  const [key, setKey] = useState('auth')

  //const isVegan = chef.diets[0].isVegan
  //const isVegetarian = chef.diets[0].isVegetarian

  console.log(isVegan)

  return (
    <FormContainer className="profileEditPage">
      <h1>Chef Profile</h1>
      <Form className='profileEditPageForm' onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Tabs id="profileEditPageTabs" activeKey={key} onSelect={(k) => setKey(k)}>
          <Tab eventKey='auth' title="Auth">
            <Form.Group controlId='first_name'>
              <Form.Label>First Name</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type='text'
                placeholder='Enter your first name'
                value={first_name}
                onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
                required
              >
              </Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group controlId='last_name'>
              <Form.Label>Last Name</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type='text'
                placeholder='Enter your last name'
                value={last_name}
                onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)}
                required
              >
              </Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group controlId='username'>
              <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type='text'
                placeholder='Enter a username'
                value={username}
                onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                required
              >
              </Form.Control>
              <Form.Text className='muted'>Your username will be public</Form.Text>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group controlId='email'>
              <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type='email'
                placeholder='Enter your email'
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                required
              >
              </Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group controlId='password'>
              <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type='password'
                placeholder='Enter your password'
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              >
              </Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group controlId='confirmPassword'>
              <Form.Label>Confirm Password</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type='password'
                placeholder='Confirm password'
                value={confirmPassword}
                onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
              >
              </Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>
          </Tab>
          <Tab eventKey='chef-detail' title="Chef Detail">
            <Form.Group controlId='isVegan'>
              <Form.Check
                type='checkbox'
                label='Vegan?'
                checked={isVegan}
                value={isVegan}
                onChange={(e) => setIsVegan(e.target.checked)}
              />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group controlId='bio'>
              <Form.Label>Chef Bio</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                as='textarea'
                rows='5'
                maxLength='240'
                placeholder='Enter bio'
                value={bio}
                onChange={(e) => setBio(e.target.value)}
              >
              </Form.Control>
              <Form.Text className='muted'>Your bio will be public</Form.Text>
            </Form.Group>
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>

        <Button type='submit' variant='primary'>
          Update
        </Button>
      </Form>


    </FormContainer>

  )
}

export default ProfileEditPage;
```

Actions

```
export const getChefDetails = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: CHEF_DETAILS_REQUEST
    })

    const { chefLogin: { chefInfo} } = getState()

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${chefInfo.token}`
      }
    }

    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `/api/chefs/${id}`,
      config
    )

    dispatch({
      type: CHEF_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data
    })

  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: CHEF_DETAILS_FAILURE,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    })
  }
}

export const updateChefProfile = (chef) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: CHEF_UPDATE_PROFILE_REQUEST
    })

    const { chefLogin: { chefInfo } } = getState()

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${chefInfo.token}`
      }
    }

    const { data } = await axios.put(
      `/api/chefs/profile`,
      chef,
      config
    )

    dispatch({
      type: CHEF_UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
      payload: data
    })

    dispatch({
      type: CHEF_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: data
    })

    localStorage.setItem('chefInfo', JSON.stringify(data))

  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: CHEF_UPDATE_PROFILE_FAILURE,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    })
  }
}
```

Reducers

```
export const chefDetailsReducer = (state = { chef: { } }, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case CHEF_DETAILS_REQUEST:
      return { ...state, loading: true }
    case CHEF_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, chef: action.payload }
    case CHEF_DETAILS_FAILURE:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
    case CHEF_DETAILS_RESET:
      return {
        chef: {}
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export const chefUpdateProfileReducer = (state = { }, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case CHEF_UPDATE_PROFILE_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true }
    case CHEF_UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, success: true, chefInfo: action.payload }
    case CHEF_UPDATE_PROFILE_FAILURE:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
    case CHEF_UPDATE_PROFILE_RESET:
      return { }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Controller

```
// @description Get chef profile
// @route GET /api/chefs/profile
// @access Private
const getChefProfile = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const chef = await Chef.findById(req.chef._id)

  if(chef) {
    res.json({
      _id: chef._id,
      first_name: chef.first_name,
      last_name: chef.last_name,
      username: chef.username,
      email: chef.email,
      bio: chef.bio,
      isVegan: chef.isVegan
    })
  } else {
    res.status(404)
    throw new Error('Chef not found')
  }
})

// @description Update chef profile
// @route PUT /api/chefs/profile
// @access Private
const updateChefProfile = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const chef = await Chef.findById(req.chef._id)

  if(chef) {
    chef.first_name = req.body.first_name || chef.first_name
    chef.last_name = req.body.last_name || chef.last_name
    chef.username = req.body.username || chef.username
    chef.email = req.body.email || chef.email
    chef.bio = req.body.bio || chef.bio
    chef.isVegan = req.body.isVegan || chef.isVegan

    if (req.body.password) {
      chef.password = req.body.password
    }

    const updatedChef = await chef.save()

    res.json({
      _id: updatedChef._id,
      first_name: updatedChef.first_name,
      last_name: updatedChef.last_name,
      username: updatedChef.username,
      email: updatedChef.email,
      bio: updatedChef.bio,
      isVegan: updatedChef.isVegan,
      token: generateToken(updatedChef._id),
    })

  } else {
    res.status(404)
    throw new Error('Chef not found')
  }
})
```

Comment: In the snippet shared, `isVegan` is part of local component state, not your redux state. Storing/duplicating state is a react anti-pattern. Which state isn't updating?

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for the comment and taking time to help. Unfortunately I am not sure I am understanding your question as I am able to update an object such as 'first_name' but not 'diets' (which ultimately stores 'isVegan'). For example, if I virtually mimic the setup of 'isVegan' for 'first_name' (with minor adjustments) and then use a function inside my form (e.g. 'onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}' ) my state updates locally and in my database. So I guess my follow-up question would be, do I need to do something on my backend? Maybe inside the controller?

Comment: You have `isVegan` local component state. You also have some `isVegan` in your redux state. Which state are you unable to modify? Are you saying your `updateChefProfile` action isn't updating the redux store? Can you include your actions and reducers?

Comment: Updated to include actions and reducers. I did confirm that when I check and uncheck the checkbox the local state of isVegan toggles between true and false so understand what is being said that 'isVegan' is a local component state.

Comment: In `updateChefProfile ` have you validated that `data` is what you expect it to be from the PUT request? Checked the response? Do you have the redux-devtool installed so you can monitor your store from the browser's devtools? Are the correct actions (and payloads) dispatched as expected?

Comment: @DrewReese I do have redux-devtools installed and that is what I was showing in the snapshot above. When I look at the actions / payloads  everything works BESIDES isVegan. Including my controller now as well in case that helps. My hunch is that I am getting isVegan from chef.diets[0] but when I have the local state of isVegan I am not updating chef.diets[0].isVegan but rather just isVegan (which isn't an object in my database).

Comment: You have `isVegan` packed in `chef` in the `updateChefProfile` action creator. This is sent in PUT request to `"/api/chefs/profile"`. This endpoint appears to return *some* data that you just shove back in state with both the `CHEF_DETAILS_SUCCESS` and `CHEF_UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS` actions. Seems you need to check: (1) the endpoint is correctly receiving, processing, and returning the correct "data", (2) your reducer(s) correctly handle the "data" `payload from the dispatched actions. Sounds like you aren't getting the data back that you expect if actions/payloads are correct but `isVegan`.

Comment: 1) I believe the endpoint is correctly receiving, processing, and returning the correct "data". I say this because the state components I excluded from my ProfileEditPage component work without issue. I can include those in my component above if that is helpful? 2) The data payload is working but always lists isVegan as true (regardless of my local state which I know updates when I check and uncheck the checkbox). Any other object in the payload will update correctly (i.e. text input in the form). Is there anything else I can share on my end to help resolve this issue?

Comment: "I believe the endpoint is correctly receiving, processing, and returning the correct 'data'", isn't a good validation. Does the network response have the correct `isVegan` value? Does `data` from `const { data } = await axios.put(...` have the updated `isVegan` value? When you look in the devtools at the dispatched actions I mentioned, do they have the correct `isVegan` value? You need to trace the `isVegan` value from the app, to the update action, to the API, to the API response, to the success action, to the reducer, to your UI. Where does it change to something you don't expect.

Comment: Apologies if I am not clear or am not understanding your questions (new to React). When I look at the devtools, my CHEF_UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCESS and CHEF_DETAILS_SUCCESS actions pass a payload of isVegan: true regardless of the local component state. If I were to change the first_name, last_name, username, email, or bio the payload changes for both of these actions. What I was trying to say earlier has been that my PUT method is working for all the other objects. This makes me believe my Action and Reducer is correct. Does that help or make sense?

Comment: No worries. I am inclined to agree since the black box here appears to be your API. You send data in from the app, and store response back in state. If the state is incorrect then I think you need to focus on your API's handling of the `isVegan` data. I was just suggesting you specifically track `isVegan` as much as possible to ensure you aren't mutating it somewhere along the line (I don't see indication of that, but is better to check and rule it out anyway).

Comment: If focusing on how my API is handling the isVegan data, would it be correct to assume that I should focus on my controller? I don't believe this is relevant but I am using Node.js and MongoDB in my backend. The controller is the only place where I specifically call out different objects which is why I continue to loop back to this. Should my res.json object in the updateChefProfile be more specific? I have tried a number of variations of 'chef.diets[0].isVegan' without any positive results. Or if the payload doesn't update in my action should I continue to focus only on the client side?

Comment: Anything that touches the data going to the backend and handles the response is relevant. Sorry, I had somehow completely overlooked your controller logic. I think I see the issue, the response object places `isVegan` in the response object root and the success action just saves it in this format (*versus processing the payload to also update the `diets` array*). However, I don't see from any of the actions, reducers, or controllers where this nested state comes from.

Comment: The nested state is from how the data is stored in my database / model. The snapshot above shows that the 'chef' object stores an object of 'diets' which has one array at index '0' that holds isVegan. Written another way, chef.diets[0].isVegan = true. To your point, I think we may agree. I am just saving 'isVegan' but 'isVegan' needs to be saved insides of chef --> diets[0]. This is what I am struggling to access.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

After much back and forth I believe the issue is with how the response "payload" is stored back in state by the reducer. The response object is a flat object with `isVegan` at the root, but in state `isVegan` is in a nested `diets` array.

```
res.json({
  _id: updatedChef._id,
  first_name: updatedChef.first_name,
  last_name: updatedChef.last_name,
  username: updatedChef.username,
  email: updatedChef.email,
  bio: updatedChef.bio,
  isVegan: updatedChef.isVegan,
  token: generateToken(updatedChef._id),
})
```

The reducer takes the payload and also saves it directly to a `chefInfo` property and overwriting any existing data.

```
export const chefUpdateProfileReducer = (state = { }, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    ...

    case CHEF_UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, success: true, chefInfo: action.payload }

    ...
  }
}
```

## Solution

Reducer should merge in response payload. In your redux screenshot I don't see a `chefInfo` key so I'll write this to match the screenshot as closely as possible.

```
export const chefUpdateProfileReducer = (state = { }, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    ...

    case CHEF_UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
      const {
        _id,
        isVegan,
        token,
        ...chefDetails // i.e. first & last name, username, email, bio
      } = action.payload;

      return {
        ...state, // <-- shallow copy state
        loading: false,
        success: true,
        chef: {
          ...state.chef, // <-- shallow copy existing chef details
          ...chefDetails, // shallow copy new chef details
          diets: state.chef.diets.map(diet => diet._id === _id ? { // <-- map existing state
            ...diet, // <-- shallow copy diet object
            isVegan // <-- overwrite isVegan property
          } : diet),
        },
      };

    ...
  }
}
```

***Note:** This is a best guess to state structures and types since your reducers appear to have a very minimally defined initial state, so this likely needs to be tweaked to fits your exact state structure.*

Comment: Appreciate the solution. I am getting an error " Unexpected token, expected "," " related to the last "{" in the line with the map function.

Comment: @jasontulloch Perhaps your IDE isn't setup/configured for trailing commas, you could probably just remove it. I type them out of habit. Let me run this through an IDE to be sure. Oops, it's a ternary operation and I simply forgot the ternary `?`...added to code. Sorry.

Comment: @jasontulloch That is [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Everything within the `{}` are the declared variables. Are you on ES6 JS?

Comment: Definitely helped! Now I am getting an "Unreachable code" error which seems to be in regards to the FAILURE and RESET constants. I am on ES6.

Comment: @jasontulloch I just copied/pasted the reducer function from my solution into a codesandbox and added back in all the other cases and (other than all the action types/etc being undefined) it is correct, it can reach the trailing action cases. Maybe you missed a closing curly boy `}`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still having issues and have verified the issue isn't related to the nested array. I updated my code above to no longer nest isVegan and place it on the same level as all the other objects (i.e. first_name, last_name, etc.). Everything in my form updates without any issue besides isVegan. This makes me very confident that the issue is either related to how checkboxes work or that isVegan is a boolean and the value is not toggling between true and false. **apologies for jumping around ** I am also reading that preventDefault can cause issues with checkboxes...

Comment: @jasontulloch Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue? I copy/pasted the entire form component (commented out the redux bits) and see that `isVegan` correctly toggles in local component state, and the correct current `isVegan` state is seen in the submit handler.

Comment: Trying to upload the on codesandbox but having trouble since I have a few private .env variables. I pushed my repository to github and made it public... https://github.com/jasontulloch/recipe-book The 4 .env variables missing that I believe you would need to add on your end are NODE_ENV = development, PORT = 5000, MONGO_URI (would need to set up MongoDB), and JWT_SECRET = anything

Comment: Update. The checkbox ONLY works if isVegan is initially false. Not sure if this helps, but gave me some bit of hope.

Comment: @jasontulloch Which `isVegan` value are you referring to? The local component state, or what it gets set to in the effect when your redux store is updated? I guess it still isn't clear at all what isn't working. Previously I copied your `ProfileEditPage` UI code into a sandbox and the `isVegan` checkbox value correctly updated in local state, and the correct current value was accessible in `submitHandler`. I still think you've some issue with either your reducer, your API endpoint logic, or both.

Comment: I think the issue is that I am storing duplicative state values in my store. I was able to easily setState locally and in my database with a separate Action (different part of my App). What I have learned is that I need to change all the isVegan values to false when the checkbox is checked vs unchecked. For example, I have made some progress by creating a function and try to change every isVegan variable I can think of to false (i.e. isVegan, chef.isVegan, chefInfo.isVegan, chefLogin.isVegan, chefInfoUpdate.isVegan). Still not working but slightly closer.

Comment: WE DID IT!!!!! I am not entirely sure why, but I had to destructure isVegan from the request body in my controller and then set chef.isVegan to it. I did not have to do this approach for any of my other variables (non of them are booleans), but nonetheless it is now working. I know this post turned into a long back and forth, but I seriously appreciate your help! Learned a lot along the way.

Comment: @jasontulloch Probably an important lesson regarding having a single source of truth, and deriving other "state" from the source of truth. :) Cheers.